# XPath substring of a sequence with multiple items?

Tags: xml, xpath

i have this xml fragment:

```
     <Route> Bangkok 05.00, Puket 06.30 
     </Route>
```

i need the name of the first city without the time. in this example here its "Bangkok".

i tried it with:

```
//Route/substring-before(text()," ")
```

and got the failure Unable to perform XPath operation. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of substring-before() ("Bangkok 05.00, Puket 06.30", "")

can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

As a naive approach you can use

```
substring-before(normalize-space(//Route/text()[1]),' ')
```

to get `Bangkok`. But this only gets cities that have no space in their name.

Getting those would be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
string-join(
     tokenize(
         normalize-space(
            tokenize($a//Route, ",")[1]
         )
         , "\s+"
    )[position() != last()]
    , " "
)
```